# How to find even sum

Tags: python

I need to find the sum of all even numbers below the inserted number. For example if I insert 8 then the sum would be 2+4+6+8=20. If I insert 9 then it also needs to be 20.  And it needs to be based on recursion.

This is what I have so far:

```
def even(a):
    if a == 0:


    else:
        even(a - 1)

even(8)
```

I cannot figure out what to change under the "if" part for it to give the right outcome

Comment: @DavidS They have clearly given it a fair go, I am happy to help them out given their current attempt at a solution

Answer (score 3):

If the function is called with an odd number, `n`, then you can immediately call again with the number below (an even).

Then if the function is called with an even number return that even number plus the result of summing all the even numbers below this number by calling again with `n - 2`.

Finally, your base case occurs when `n = 0`. In this case just return `0`.

So we have

```
def even_sum(n):
    if n % 2 == 1: # n is odd
        return even_sum(n - 1)
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    return n + even_sum(n - 2)
```

which works as expected

```
>>> even_sum(8)
20
>>> even_sum(9)
20
>>> even_sum(0)
0
```

Answer (score 1):

To design a recursive algorithm, the first thing to wonder is "In what cases can my algorithm return an answer trivially?". In your case, the answer is "If it is called with 0, the algorithm answers 0". Hence, you can write:

```py
def even(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
```

Now the next question is "Given a particular input, how can I reduce the size of this input, so that it will eventually reach the trivial condition?"

If you have an even number, you want to have this even number + the sum of even numbers below it, which is the result of `even(n-2)`. If you have an odd number, you want to return the sum of even numbers below it. Hence the final version of your function is:

```py
def even(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 0
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n + even(n - 2)
    return even(n - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## For a recursive solution:

```
def evenSum(N): return 0 if N < 2 else N - N%2 + evenSum(N-2)
```

If you were always given an even number as input, you could simply recurse using N + f(N-2).

For example:  8 + ( 6 + (4 + ( 2 + 0 ) ) )

But the odd numbers will require that you strip the odd bit in the calculation (e.g. subtracting 1 at each recursion)

For example:  9-1 + ( 7-1 + ( 5-1 + ( 3-1 + 0 ) ) )

You can achieve this stripping of odd bits by subtracting the modulo 2 of  the input value.  This subtracts zero for even numbers and one for odd numbers.

**adjusting your code**

Your approach is recursing by 1, so it will go through both the even and odd numbers down to zero (at which point it must stop recursing and simply return zero).

Here's how you can adjust it:

- Return a value of zero when you are given zero as input
- Make sure to return the computed value that comes from the next level of recursion (you are missing `return` in front of your call to `even(a-1)`
- Add the parameter value when it is even but don't add it when it is odd

...

```
def even(a):
    if a == 0   : return 0             # base case, no further recusion
    if a%2 == 1 : return even(a-1)     # odd number:  skip to even number
    return a + even(a-1)               # even number: add with recursion
                                       # a+even(a-2) would be better
```

**A trick to create a recursive function**

An easy way to come up with the structure of a recursive function is to be very optimistic and imagine that you already have one that works.  Then determine how you would use the result of that imaginary function to produce the next result.  That will be the recursive part of the function.

Finally, find a case where you would know the answer without using the function.  That will be your exit condition.

In this case (sum of even numbers), imagine you already have a function `magic(x)` that gives you the answer for x.  How would you use it to find a solution for `n` given the result of `magic(n-1)` ?

If `n` is even, add it to `magic(n-1)`.  If `n` is odd, use `magic(n-1)` directly.

Now, to find a smaller `n` where we know the answer without using `magic()`.  Well if `n` is less than 2 (or zero) we know that `magic(n)` will return zero so we can give that result without calling it.

So our recursion is *"n+magic(n-1) if n is even, else magic(n-1)"*

and our stop condition is *"zero if n < 2"*

Now substitute `magic` with the name of your function and the magic is done.

## For an O(1) solution:

Given that the sum of numbers from 1 to N can be calculated with N*(N+1)//2, you can get half of the sum of even numbers if you use N//2 in the formula. Then multiply the result by 2 to obtain the sum of even numbers.

so  `(N//2)*(N//2+1)` will give the answer directly in O(1) time:

```
N = 8
print((N//2)*(N//2+1))

# 20


# other examples:
for N in range(10):
    print(N,N//2*(N//2+1))

# 0 0
# 1 0
# 2 2
# 3 2
# 4 6
# 5 6
# 6 12
# 7 12
# 8 20
# 9 20
```

Visually, you can see the progression like this:

```
1..n    : 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
∑n      : 1   3   6   10  15  21  28  36  n(n+1)/2
n/2     : 0   1   1   2   2   3   3   4

1..n/2  :     1       2       3       4   
∑n/2    :     1       3       5       10  half of the result
2∑n/2   :     2       6       10      20  sum of even numbers
```

So we simply replace N with N//2 in the formula and multiply the result by 2:

```
N*(N+1)//2       --> replace N with N//2 -->  N//2*(N//2+1)//2
N//2*(N//2+1)//2 --> multiply by 2       -->  N//2*(N//2+1)
```

Another way to see it is using Gauss's visualisation of the sum of numbers but using even numbers:

```
ascending    2   4   6   8   ... N-6  N-4  N-2  N   (where N is even)
descending   N   N-2 N-4 N-6 ... 8    6    4    2
             --- --- --- ---     ---  ---  ---  ---
totals       N+2 N+2 N+2 N+2 ... N+2  N+2  N+2  N+2 (N/2 times N+2)
```

Because we added the even numbers twice, once in ascending order and once in descending order, the sum of all the totals will be twice the sum of even numbers (we need to divide that sum by 2 to get what we are looking for).

```
sum of evens: N/2*(N+2)/2 --> N/2*(N/2+1)
```

The `N/2(N/2+1)` formulation allows us to supply the formula with an odd number and get the right result by using integer division which absorbs the 'odd bit': `N//2(N//2+1)`

**Recursive O(1) solution**

Instead of using the integer division to absorb the odd bit, you could use recursion with the polynomial form of N/2*(N+2)/2:  N^2/4 + N/2

```
def sumEven(n):
    if n%2 == 0 : return n**2/4 + n/2  # exit condition
    return sumEven(n-1)                # recursion
```

*Technically this is recursive although in practice it will never go deeper than 1 level*

Answer (score 1):

Both with o(n) time complexity

With For loop

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))  # given number to find sum
my_sum = 0
for n in range(num + 1):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        my_sum += n
print(my_sum)
```

With recursion

```
 def my_sum(num):
    if num == 0:
        return 0
    if num % 2 == 1:
        return my_sum(num - 1)
    return num + my_sum(num - 2)
```

always avoid O(n^2) and greater time complexity

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

```py
>>> n = 5
>>> sum(range(0, n+1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

with minimum complexity

```
# include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num, sum, i;

    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    i = num;
    
    if (num % 2 != 0)
        num = num -1;

    sum = (num * (num + 2)) / 4;


    printf("The sum of even numbers upto %d is %d\n\n", i, sum);
}
```

It is a C program and could be used in any language with respective syntax.

Answer (score -1):

> And it needs to be based on recursion.

Though you want a recursion one, I still want to share this dp solution with detailed steps to solve this problem.

## Dynamic Programming

dp[i] represents the even sum among [0, i] which I denote as *nums*.

1. Case1: When i is 0, there is one number 0 in *nums*. dp[0] is 0.
2. Case2: When i is 1, there are two numbers 0 and 1 in *nums*. dp[1] is still 0.
3. Case3: When i is 2, there are three numbers 0, 1 and 2 in *nums*. dp[2] is 2.
4. Case4: When i is greater than 2, there are two more cases

   1. If i is odd, `dp[i] = dp[i-1]`. Since i is odd, it is the same with [0, i-1].
   2. If i is even, `dp[i] = dp[i-2] + i` by adding the current even number to the even sum among [0, i-2] (i-1 is odd, so won't be added).

      PS. `dp[i] = dp[i-1] + i` is also ok. The difference is how you initialize dp.

Since we want the even sum among [0, n], we return dp[n]. You can conclude this from the first three cases.

```py
def even_sum(n):
    dp = []

    # Init
    dp.append(0)  # dp[0] = 0
    dp.append(0)  # dp[1] = 0

    # DP
    for i in range(2, n+1):         # n+1 because range(i, j) results [i, j) and you take n into account
        if i % 2 == 1:              # n is odd
            dp.append(dp[i-1])      # dp[i] = dp[i-1]
        else:                       # n is even
            dp.append(dp[i-2] + i)  # dp[i] = dp[i-2] + i

    return dp[-1]
```